# Why is unreachable code in constexpr if evaluated?

Tags: c++, c++20, if-constexpr

I had expected the compiler to allow invalid or error statements in unreachable code involving constexpr if:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct ret_t;
struct only_declared_t;

auto test = [](auto a) {
    if constexpr(std::is_invocable_r_v<ret_t, decltype(a), int>) {
        return a(42);
    } else {
        return 42;
    }

    // I expect to never reach that statement, but the compiler complains
    static_assert(false, "This code should never be reached."); 
    return only_declared{};
};

int main() {
    std::cerr << "Result is " << test(10) << "\n";
}
```

Any explanation/workaround would be helpful

Comment: The compiler has to keep parsing the code, if for nothing else just to find out where the function ends.

Comment: As for a workaround: throw an exception instead of static_assert?

Comment: you can put `static_assert`s almost anywhere, they need not be "executed" to cause an error

Comment: as a workaround, just remove it? No code after the `else` is reachable

Comment: Basically this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53818624/why-does-if-constexpr-require-an-else-to-work - But even then, you can't just unconditionally have a false static assertion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53945490/how-to-assert-that-a-constexpr-if-else-clause-never-happen - Templates aren't macros, they are part of the type system. And `if constexpr` doesn't allow token soup, it still has constraints

Comment: You 'had expected the compiler to allow invalid or error statements in unreachable code' why? 'Unreachable' at runtime doesn't mean the compiler doesn't have to compile it, and certainly doesn't mean it doesn't have to be syntactically or semantically correct.

Answer (score -2):

`static_assert` works in compile time, so it generates compile-time errors regardless of code reachability. You can use `assert` for run-time checks. `assert` shall not be evaluated.

Comment: It has nothing to do with `static_assert`. *All* code gets compiled regardless of reachability.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne, you are absolutely right.

Comment: This is factually wrong to a horrendous extent. Please don't guess at an answer, it misleads people.

Comment: @PasserBy C++ standard says: In a static_assert-declaration, the constant-expression shall be a contextually converted constant expression of type bool. If the value of the expression when so converted is true, the declaration has no effect.
Otherwise, the program is ill-formed, and the resulting diagnostic message shall include the text of the string-literal, if one is supplied, except that characters not in the basic source character set are not required to appear in the diagnostic message. What is factually wrong?

Comment: The quote in your comment is fine. Your answer on the other hand, is not clear at all.